# Error in installing Jenkins

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, jenkins

I am facing issues while installing **jenkins** on my **ubuntu14.04** server. Java version is 1.8.

***Steps followed as root:***

```
wget --no-check-certificate -qO - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list’
apt-get upgrade
apt-get update
apt-get install jenkins
```

***The output for apt-get update:***

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repos.sensuapp.org/apt/dists/sensu/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://repos.sensuapp.org/apt/dists/sensu/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'repos.sensuapp.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

***Output for apt-get install jenkins:***

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jenkins : Depends: sysvinit-utils (>= 2.88dsf-50) but 2.88dsf-41ubuntu6.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 reached it's end of life in 2019. It does not receive any updates anymore and should not be used any more. It is most probably just too old. Upgrade it to a supported release.

Comment: This is for a legacy application under the process of migration. We need this installation to be done now, until the migration is complete (which will take a month). Is there any way in which it can be installed?

Comment: Download `war` file and use it

Comment: what was the old version of jenkins that you were using on ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Jenkins version : 2.10

Comment: I was able to complete the setup using war file and data from one of our existing ubuntu14.04 servers where jenkins was installed.